# ERROR CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask Error while running deployment scheduler

Tags: svn, wso2, cluster-computing, synchronization, wso2-esb

Hello I have a problem with my wso2 cluster SVN sync,the error as follow when wso2 ESB managerNode start  ：

```
2013-09-04 15:32:34,781 [-] [pool-10-thread-1] ERROR CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask Error while running deployment scheduler.. 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2367)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:130)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:114)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:415)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.getFullMessage(SVNErrorMessage.java:257)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:58)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:163)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:272)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:265)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:261)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:316)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:296)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:278)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:542)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.svnkit.SvnKitClientAdapter.getStatus(SvnKitClientAdapter.java:144)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:528)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:521)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.cleanupDeletedFiles(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:486)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.subversion.SVNBasedArtifactRepository.checkout(SVNBasedArtifactRepository.java:352)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizer.checkout(DeploymentSynchronizer.java:181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.deployment.synchronizer.internal.DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.update(DeploymentSynchronizerServiceImpl.java:87)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.deploymentSyncUpdate(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have provided minimum hardware requirements provided in WSO2 product documentation. If so try allowing more memory to be used by the JVM using the -Xmx VM argument. For instance, java -Xmx1024m